# activity restart due to Configuration Change

Tags: android, android-activity, configuration, orientation-changes, bluetooth-keyboard

My activity is getting restarted, to avoid this I have added the possible configuration changes in my Android manifest still activity getting restarted. The android manifest as below

I have get the configuration at runtime and logged in Log file, The older configuration as follows

{1.0 ?mcc?mnc [en_IN] ldltr sw800dp w1280dp h728dp 160dpi xlrg land finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1280, 800) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1280, 752) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=standard mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_90} s.5}

And the changed configuration as below

{1.0 ?mcc?mnc [en_IN] ldltr sw800dp w1280dp h728dp 160dpi xlrg land finger qwerty/v/v dpad/v winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1280, 800) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1280, 752) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=standard mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_90} s.7}

Please could you tell me what is this s.5 to s.7 change stands for?

Answer (score 0):

`s.NUMBER` seems to be just a serial number of the change.

If you connect and disconnect the device, you should see this number increases for each configuration change.